# ¿Cómo puedo darle más recursos a spider?

Tags: python-3.7

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de que pueda darle más memoria a los programas que ejecuto en spider, ya que este se me apaga porque necesito más recursos y me vive borrando lo que codifico.

Comment: por favor añade más información. Así como está formulada la pregunta es difícil de responder

Comment: `Spyder` no parece tener culpa de la gestión de la memoria. El problema parece que viene más bien sobre cómo estás gestionando tú la memoria mediante tu programa. Quizá debes repensar el código que estás escribiendo para que no te dé `MemoryError`. Si pones el código del programa, la RAM de tu PC y lo que estás intentando abrir te podamos dar más información.